# Передача данных в другой класс

Tags: android, map, callback

У меня есть 2 класса.

Активити Класс 1, и обычный класс 2.

В первом классе, находится SimpleAdapter, а во втором классе сетевой запрос.

**Вопрос:** как мне передать данные адаптеру со второго класса, первому?

Вот сам интерфейс

```
public interface ResponseCallback {
    void response(ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> response);
}
```

Вот класс активити:

```
public class FriendMsgActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ResponseCallback {

private ListView listView;
String LOG_TAG = "FriendLOG";

ArrayList data;
EditText editText;
Handler mHandler;

ChatMsgAdapter sAdapter;

protected String LV_KEY = Auth.key;
protected int LV_USID = Integer.parseInt(Auth.id);
protected int GET_ID = Integer.parseInt(FriendActivity.get_id);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend_msg);
    setTitle(get_login);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvFriendMsg);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.form_input);
}

@Override
public void response(ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> response) {

    sAdapter = new ChatMsgAdapter(this, response);

    if(sAdapter == null) {
        listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    } else {
        sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

class RefreshActivity extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                new UpdateMsg(FriendMsgActivity.this).execute();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "get handler");
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.post(new RefreshActivity());
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MainActivity: onStart()");
}
}
```

Вот парсер Json:

```
public class ResponseMsgJson {

String LOG_TAG = "FriendLOG";

public ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> parseData(String response) {

    ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> data = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

    try {
        dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray chat = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < chat.length(); i++) {
            ResponseMsgArray rms = new ResponseMsgArray();
            JSONObject msgList = chat.getJSONObject(i);
            String error = msgList.getString("error");
            if (!error.equals("0")) {
                if (error.equals("1")) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ошибка 1!..");
                }
                if (error.equals("2")) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ошибка 2!..");
                }
            } else {
                String msg = msgList.getString("msg");
                String msg_id = msgList.getString("msg_id");
                String msg_time = msgList.getString("msg_time");
                String msg_id_us = msgList.getString("msg_id_user");

                rms.setMsg(msg);
                rms.setMsg_id(msg_id);
                rms.setMsg_time(msg_time);
                rms.setMsg_id_us(msg_id_us);
                data.add(rms);

            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return data;
    }
}
```

AsynckTasc:

```
public class UpdateMsg extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray>, Void, ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray>> {

String LOG_TAG = "FriendLOG";

protected String LV_KEY = Auth.key;
protected int LV_USID = Integer.parseInt(Auth.id);
protected int GET_ID = Integer.parseInt(FriendActivity.get_id);

private ResponseCallback callback;

public UpdateMsg(ResponseCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> doInBackground(ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray>... params) {

    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] data = null;
    String parammetrs = "FriendMsgLoad=true&get_id=" + GET_ID + "&us_id=" + LV_USID + "&key=" + LV_KEY;

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, parammetrs);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://сайтточкаруиндекс.php");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(parammetrs.getBytes().length));
        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        data = parammetrs.getBytes("UTF-8");
        os.write(data);
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }

        if (content.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return new ResponseMsgJson().parseData(content.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> result) {
    callback.response(result);
}
}
```

Сам адаптер:

```
public class ChatMsgAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResponseMsgArray> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> data;


protected String LV_KEY = Auth.key;
protected int LV_USID = Integer.parseInt(Auth.id);
protected int GET_ID = Integer.parseInt(FriendActivity.get_id);


String LOG_TAG = "FriendLOG";

public ChatMsgAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> values) {
    super(context,R.layout.activity_friend_msg, values);

    this.data = values;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View v;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if(type == LV_USID) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_msg_adapter, null);

        TextView user_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        TextView user_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);

        user_text.setText(data.get(position).getMsg());
        user_date.setText(data.get(position).getMsg_time());

    } else if (type == GET_ID) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talker, null);

        TextView talker_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        TextView talker_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);
        talker_text.setText(data.get(position).getMsg());
        talker_date.setText(data.get(position).getMsg_time());

    } else {
        //Если нет например сообщений
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_null, null);
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int newPosition = Integer.parseInt(data.get(position).getMsg_id_us());
    return newPosition;
}
}
```

Ну и сам ResponseMsgArray:

```
public class ResponseMsgArray {

private String msg;
private String msg_id;
private String msg_time;
private String msg_id_us;

//************************ getters ******************************************

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public String getMsg_id() {
    return msg_id;
}

public String getMsg_time() {
    return msg_time;
}

public String getMsg_id_us() {
    return msg_id_us;
}

//*************************** setters *****************************************

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public void setMsg_id(String msg) {
    this.msg_id = msg;
}

public void setMsg_time(String msg) {
    this.msg_time = msg;
}

public void setMsg_id_us(String msg) {
    this.msg_id_us = msg;
}
}
```

Выложил в принципе уже готовую задачу. Может кому пригодится, пользуйтесь :)

Comment: у вас точно два класса - ни одно из которых не является активити?

Comment: Прошу прощения....класс 1 является активити

Comment: Создать экземпляр адаптера в активити, вероятно?

Comment: @Asgard что именно вы имеете ввиду? В самой активити адаптер у меня инициализирован

Comment: приведите код, вот что я имею ввиду.

Comment: @Asgard, в самой активити, у меня есть метод dataCh (ArrayList data, String [] from, int [] to), а в классе с сетевым запросом, после всех проверок, я передаю данные в dataCh (...) . Выходит ошибка `java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`

Comment: Вы меня не поняли, вам необходимо обновить вопрос, в который вы закинете оба класса, со всем имеющимся кодом.

Comment: и судя по ошибке, вы пытаетесь сделать нечто, до создания активити(до метода onCreate)

Comment: Я обновил свой вопрос

Comment: @sergei1094, что мешает сделать коллбэк и вернуть результат куда хочешь?

Comment: @Сергей, у вас нет случайно примеров кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример колбэка:
там, где получаем данные:

```
private OnMessageListener callback;

public interface OnMessageListener {
    void onMessage(SomeType mess);
}

public void setOnMessageListener(OnMessageListener listener) {
    callback = listener;
}
```

там, где хотим данные обновить подписываемся на onMessage(...)
   new onMessageListener{...}

только это нужно не в адаптере делать.
данные нужно отдельно хранить, а в адаптере по событию их обновлять.

Comment: Спасибо, перестроил свою программу с использованием CallBack интерфейса. Нашёл очень полезную статью http://dajver.blogspot.com/2015/10/callback-android.html может кому пригодится. Теперь я вернулся снова в старый век. Сейчас у меня данные отображаются, но при истечении времени Handler'a, мой ListView опять сбрасывает позицию скролла. Не могли бы вы чисто символически показать пример обновления адаптера руководствуясь данной статьёй? Моё текущее активити обновил в вопросе

Comment: @sergei1094 не понятно, что именно и как не работает. в указанном примере(статье) все более чем конкретно объяснено. я не понимаю твоего Handler'а от слова совсем. поэтому все, что могу предложить - самому отладить. ставим метку на callback.response(result); - проверяем, что там возвращается; затем соотв. на sAdapter = new ChatMsgAdapter(this, response); - пришло ли сюда, сколько раз и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать использовать библиотеку EventBus (проще всего), либо же сделать интерфейс (так называемый калбек) и передать его экземпляр из адаптера во второй класс, а от туда дергать его и передавать в него данные.

Comment: Сделал, но что делать дальше? Я запутался