# setData() - выводит повторные значения

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? У меня адаптер принимает данные с сервера и помещает их в листвью. Затем, когда поступают новые данные, я пытаюсь обновить адаптер...и как бы всё хорошо, но..
Когда приходят новые данные, например 2 сообщения, они добавляются в адаптер. Но вместе с новыми данными, добавляются и все остальные старые данные..Хотя по логам вижу что старых данных, поступивших с сервера у меня нет. Выходит что не выполняю `data.clear()`. Выполняю...`data.clear()`, мой листвью становится абсолютно пустым до следующего запроса `Handler.postDelayed();`. Снова запрос - листвью полный и с новыми данными...5 сек проходит и мой лист опять чистый...и так постоянно. Как это перебороть?

```
public class ChatMsgAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResponseMsgArray> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> data;


protected String LV_KEY = Auth.key;
protected int LV_USID = Integer.parseInt(Auth.id);
protected int GET_ID = Integer.parseInt(FriendActivity.get_id);


String LOG_TAG = "FriendLOG";

public ChatMsgAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> values) {
    super(context,R.layout.activity_friend_msg, values);

    this.data = values;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View v;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if(type == LV_USID) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_msg_adapter, null);

        TextView user_id_msg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_msg);
        TextView user_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        TextView user_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);

        user_text.setText(data.get(position).getMsg());
        user_date.setText(data.get(position).getMsg_time());
        user_id_msg.setText(data.get(position).getMsg_id());

    } else if (type == GET_ID) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talker, null);

        TextView talker_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        TextView talker_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);
        talker_text.setText(data.get(position).getMsg());
        talker_date.setText(data.get(position).getMsg_time());

    } else {
        //Если нет например сообщений
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_null, null);
    }

    return v;
}

public void setData(ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> newData) {
    addAll(newData);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int newPosition = Integer.parseInt(data.get(position).getMsg_id_us());
    return newPosition;
}
}
```

Comment: Покажите код адаптера `ChatMsgAdapter`.

Comment: В смысле? Это же стандартный метод

Comment: Покажите код всего адаптера.

Comment: Обновил свой вопрос

Comment: @post_zeew, вы мне подскажете?

Comment: Не воспроизводя пример сложно сказать. Пройдитесь отладчиком и посмотрите что, когда и куда добавляется.

Comment: @post_zeew, вот тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579311/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81/579403?noredirect=1#comment769066_579403 находятся все мои классы, в том числе активити. Может это вам поможет?

Comment: Нет, это мне не поможет.

Comment: `Пройдитесь отладчиком и посмотрите что, когда и куда добавляется.`, тут по сути то и так понятно что и куда добавляется. Не понятно то как правильно обновить данные.

Comment: А ту что, только один человек который и то уже ни чем не поможет? Люди добрые, помогите....я уже устал :(

Answer (score 1):

Повторные значения показываются из-за того, что нет установки по умолчанию.
При создании элемента, попробуйте сначала устанавливать им пустые значения, а только потом обрабатывать с помощью `if...else`